# "The Deserter" folk song, meaning of "Three hundred and three"

Tags: meaning-in-context

The folk song "The Deserter", possibly best known in [Fairport Convention's version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-ezy2WaM24), contains a verse that doesn't make much sense to me.

> Court martial, court martial, they held upon me,
> And the sentence passed upon me, three hundred and three.

What is the meaning of the expression "three hundred and three" in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It almost certainly means 303 lashes, a severe [flogging](https://www.britannica.com/topic/flogging). Sentencing to varying numbers of lashes was a common punishment in the military until the 19th century.

Comment: It's referred to here as ["the **mystical** three hundred and three (**lashes ?**)"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22three+hundred+and+three+lashes%22). So maybe that writer's not certain, but I think you're right. Not that 303 lashes was ever likely to have been a particularly *common* number, I'm sure. Just "add a few extra for the sake of it".

Comment: Also it rhymes when that three is added.

Comment: Thank you. Useful answer, voted. If I'll have nothing more *definitive* in a short time, certainly I will accept your answer.